# How to perform linear solve to a big sparse linear system

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I am facing unable to allocate that much memory problem when I try to solve a huge linear sparse system.

I think it might be helpful to use COO storage, but I don't if I really need it.

```
from scipy.sparse import diags
import numpy as np

nx=50
ny=50
nz=50

lx=1
ly=1
lz=1

dx=lx/nx
dy=ly/ny
dz=lz/nz

n1 = 2*(dy*dz+dx*dz+dx*dy)
n2 = -(dy*dz)
n3 = -(dx*dz)
n4 = -(dx*dy)

d1=np.ones((nx*ny*nz))*n1
d2temp=np.zeros((nx))
d2temp[1:nx]=n2


d2=np.tile(d2temp,ny*nz)
d2=np.delete(d2,0)

d3temp1=np.zeros((nx))
d3temp2=np.ones(((ny-1)*nx))*n3
d3temp=np.append(d3temp1,d3temp2)
d3=np.tile(d3temp,nz)
d3=d3[nx:]

d4=np.ones((nx*ny*nz-nx*ny))*n4


diagonals = [d1, d2, d2, d3, d3, d4, d4]



a=diags(diagonals, [0, -1, 1, -nx, nx, -nx*ny, nx*ny]).toarray()
b=np.ones((nx*ny*nz))
x=np.linalg.solve(a,b)
```

Comment: I see lots of code, but don't know where your problem(s) is.  The sparse formats all have methods for converting between them.  `toarray` on a sparse matrix often does produce a memory error (depending obviously on the `shape`).

Comment: sorry, here is what I want to do, after get a as a matrix, I want to ```b=np.ones((nx*ny*nz)) x=np.linalg.solve(a,b)```. I want to solve a linear system.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html has some solvers that may work with the sparse matrix, without requiring the `toarray` conversion.